# KD-160 Kohler piano audio outputs not working

Tags: piano, digital-piano, audio, live-sound

at our worship place we have a KD-160, Kohler digital piano, and it currently has an external mic hooked up to our PA system. I want to get it connected straight into our PA system via the output L/mono and R on the rear panel. I can't seem to get any sound out of it though. Unsure why.

Per the manual, "PAGE 13 - AUDIO OUTPUT CONFIGURATION" it looks like each track\virtual sound needs to be assigned to a physical output (i.e. Left&Right).

Done that, but there is no audio coming out to the PA system. However there is audio when using the output 1 and 2.

The problem is that the piano speakers are switched off with this option. The pianist finds it important to hear himself through the speakers of the piano and to be able to control the volume from his end when desired. I guess with all the different volunteers, they all use different levels at the fader and it is inconsistent for the pianist.
I did try to use the left/mono and right outputs but nothing comes out of it. Since the output 1 and 2 are working, meaning the back panel is working, I know there is an issue on the left/mono and right outputs.

Any suggestions?

I have read that some folks solder something in the headphone jack output and use that, but I would not know how to.

It would sound way better if it was connected to our PA system, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My first thoughts were to use a cheap headset, that would still allow everything else to be heard, maybe only using one earpiece. Plugged into the headphone outlet.

The second would involve a monitor speaker (foldback) which could have any mix the player wanted, but that would involve  extra cables, and perhaps a powered monitor for the pianists.